# Jquery - How to hide images when there is no stylesheet?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a CSS hack where the image is scaled, but there is a problem.

If the user switches the stylesheet off, the image used as the background is shown, sometimes the image is really huge.

Therefore, I need to hide the background div when there is no stylesheet.

I've thought about dynamically adding the image via JQuery, whilst this works -- it does not take into account whether there is no stylesheet.

How do I switch off images, or the background div when there is no stylesheet?

Thanks.

**CSS**

```
background {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px; 
 top: 0px; 
 z-index: -1;
}

.stretch {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="background">
<img src="background_1200x800.jpg" class="stretch" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you put the background in the css file?

`#id { background: url(background_1200x800.jpg) no-repeat center }`

Comment: I must be missing something (it's late in Singapore)... he can still apply the `stretch` class to the div (as well as all the other style info he has in the CSS already)

Comment: I tried putting the div in the centre, but I do not not what you mean by applying the stretch class to the div, as the background image would be unaffected and unstretched.  Could you give a bit more detail about what you mean?

Comment: Indeed I misunderstood the effect you were trying to achieve... This will not work.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.styleSheets) collection to detect if there are stylesheets loaded.

Edit: I know this is a hack to cover for another hack, but how about adding a `display:none` inline style to the image and adding a `display:block!important` to the stretch class in stylesheet.

Comment: I think this is the most reasonable solution.

Comment: I tried:

if (document.styleSheets.length == 0){
$("#background").hide();
}

As well as alerting the message -- it does not alert on change. I think this may be because it is a browser thing, and strictly not a web/javascript thing.

I tried putting display:block!important inline, and then display:block!important both to the div and the actual image, with the CSS having a display:block, whilst this looks promising, it does not hide the image when the style is off.  

I am using Firefox to test this.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be better if I just used PHP to code around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this (do this onload):

```
if(!$("style").length){
 $("#background").hide();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using .length does not appear to work as the image is still there when I click "No style".

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer does not achieve the desired effect, as I missunderstood the question.  However the following works for me:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Background to fit screen</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

      <style type="text/css">
         html {height:100%;}
         body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
         #bg {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
         #fg {position:relative; z-index:1;}a
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="bg">
        <img class="stretch" src="background_1200x800.jpg" width="0" height="0">
      </div>
      <div id="fg">
        <p>content goes in the `fg` div.</p>
      </div>
      <style type="text/css">
         #bg img {width:100%; height:100%;}
      </style>
   </body>
</html>
```

I tested this in FF3.5 (on Vista) the desired effect (no background image) is achieved when I use the Web Developer extension to turn off all styles.  With styles on the entire view-port is covered with the background image and the content is on-top of the image.

I also took a quick look in IE7 (on Vista) and Chrome (on Vista) and both show the image covering the entire viewport with the content placed on top.  I did not test turning off styles in browser other then FF3.5.

*I have no idea if the second style element in the body is valid or if it is considered a good idea or an abomination*

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought and NOT TESTED...

HTML:

```
<div id="background">
<img src="background_1200x800.jpg" height="0" width="0" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#background img {width: 100%; height: 100%}
```

Idea:

Set HTML image attributes to be zero by default. Use CSS to overide dimensions... CSS disabled let the image fall back on its own inline values.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to keep it with the image, as I don't think its totally 100% cross browser resolution.

Topic closed.